# Need help running expo init command on visual studio

Tags: react-native, expo

I am stuck at this for a long time now. Have tried everything. Can someone please help me understand why is this happening? I have attached the screenshot of the error as below

[PS C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\projects> expo init Mealtogo

Migrate to using:
› npx create-expo-app --template

√ Choose a template: » blank               a minimal app as clean as an empty canvas
Error downloading and extracting template package: Error: Could not parse JSON returned from "npm pack expo-template-blank --dry-run".

expo-template-blank-46.0.21.tgz

Error: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0
× Something went wrong while downloading and extracting the template.

Can't read JSON file: C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\projects\Mealtogo\app.json
└─ Cause: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\projects\Mealtogo\app.json'
├─ readAsync C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\json-file\src\JsonFile.ts:158:13
├─ extractAndPrepareTemplateAppAsync C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\utils\extractTemplateAppAsync.ts:25:25
└─ actionAsync C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\initAsync.ts:290:19][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avli6.png)

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
npx create-expo-app --template
```